# Can you route multiple returns to the same via?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, high-frequency, high-speed, via

New to PCB Design and layout. While routing bypass caps, I instinctively give each bypass cap its own via to the ground plane. What would be the disadvantages of having two (or more) bypass caps share the same ground via?

I suspect the consequences are more apparent in high-speed and/or high power designs, but in low-power, low-speed designs, what are the disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: Higher inductance, higher resistance both of which mean more noise and less decoupling. Low power, low speed designs shouldn't notice but at the same time there's not really much reason to try and save on vias unless you're drilling them by hand.

Comment: This is called via sharing. That may help you search for more information about it. It is never recommended which is not to say that it is never done.

Comment: If there are current pulses in one decoupling cap loop the voltage drop across the via will cause them to be seen by the other decoupled device. The resistance of a via is pretty low so it shouldn't usually be an issue, but it's worse than 2 vias and vias are usually free, so the answer is usually why not?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn9Y3a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Any current though Circuit A must pass trough the via. This will create a voltage across the via that is also shared with Circuit B.

If circuit A use allot of power and circuit B is attempting to do an accurate measurement you will create noise on circuit B.

That is always bad. On this site I may sometimes go on a rant about unimportant optimizations and spending time on unnecessary details, but this is not one of them. This might not be important for you right now, but having the mindset to always consider and adjust for return currents will save you a world of hurt later on.